# Change Login Status on Database after browser force closed or session expired

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

I have a user login data in MySQL, in condition user only can login 1 times in session. If using logout button, code are running well but if the user close the browser

```
// user_table in MySQL
   user_id      user_username      user_password      is_login
     1              xyzabc             xxxxx             0  // 0 is not
     2              abcdef             xxxxx             1  // 1 is login
     3              efghij             xxxxx             1
```

I used `is_login` for blocking access from 2nd login user. So, each account only can login once and `is_login` we used to kick user from logged in session on set `is_login` to `0`.

```
// Inside my login function
public function login()
{
   ... some validation login code ...
   // User ID accepted & login = TRUE
   $this->session->set_userdata('id', $data->user_id);
   // this query is in model, I just copy it to here
   $this->db->query('UPDATE user_table SET is_login = "1" WHERE user_id = ".$id."');
   $this->session->sess_expiration = 7200;
   $this->session->sess_expire_on_close = TRUE;
}

// Logout function in controller
public function logout() {
   $id = $this->session->userdata('id');
   // this query is in model, I just copy it to here
   $this->db->query('UPDATE user_table SET is_login = "0" WHERE user_id = ".$id."');
   $this->session->sess_destroy();
}
```

If the user are logged out using `logout` function, the code are running well.

The `is_login` column will be set on `0` again. But if the browser force closed `is_login` status is still `1`. Any solution ?

Comment: You need timestamp type column in table associated with time of login. Plus, cronjob every `$sessionTimeSpanValue` that will change status for all rows that are older than that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As indicated by @Tpojka change the is_login column to INT(11)
2. Add another column to your user table to shows the last user activity
3. Add a cronjob to SET is_login = 0 if the current system time and the last user activity is greater than expiration time
4. Whenever a user logs in, store time() value from php into DB
5. Store the same value of login time() into user session. so everytime that the user refresh a page you make check the value that you have in session with DB to understand that the user is the same or not. if not, logout the user and destroy the same. it might mean that the user is logged in from another device so he/she should be logged out from the current browser
6. every time that the user send a request and the is_login value matches the value that you have in DB, you may add and update another value in the user session. for example dte_last_activity then you can understand that if the session is expired or not for the user. don't rely on the session expiration time of the server as you might need a different expiration time.

Okay, let say that we have a user table like below:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `system_users` (
   `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `fullname` varchar(90) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
   `username` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
   `password` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `dte_login` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `dte_activity` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci;
```

**dte_login** is timestamp value that we set into the database whenever a user log in
**dte_activity** is timestamp value for the last time that the user requested something from your server and off course he was log in

Note that **dte_activity** is only needed if you need to check that a user is still active or not.

```
function login($username, $password) {
    $result = false;

    // Check from DB that the username and password is valid or not
    // IF user is valid, retrieve user_id from DB
    If (USER_IS_VALID) {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
        $_SESSION['dte_activity'] = time();
        $_SESSION['dte_login'] = time();

        $result = true;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Okay now whenever the user ask to access a page you call a sample function like below:

```
function checkLogin() {
    $result = false;

    if (!empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
         // This means that somebody is already logged in
         $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
         $dte_login = $_SESION['dte_login'];

         // We need to check if the user which is login is the same as the last user that used our website so we compare the dte_login value that we stored in session with what we have in DB
         $db_connection->query("SELECT `id` FROM `system_users` WHERE `id`={$user_id} AND `dte_login`={$dte_login};");             
         // If the above query return no result, it means that someone else logged in meanwhile and we have to log out the current user 

         if ($db_connection->num_rows>0) {
             // Now we need to check if his/her session is still valid or not
             $EXPIERY = 300; // in seconds (in this case, 5 minutes) 
             $now = time();
             if ($now-$_SESSION['dte_activity']<$EXPIERY) {
                 // The user session is still valid and we need to update database
                 $db_connection->query("UPDATE `system_users` SET `dte_activity`={$now} WHERE id={$user_id};");
                 $_SESSION['dte_activity'] = $now;

                 $result = true; // Means that someone is active
             } else {
                 session_destroy();
             }
         } else {
             session_destroy();
         }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I'll try it first & I really appreciate it if you give me an example using code. thank you.

Comment: I updated my answer with php sample code. but note that if you want to clean your database from expired users, then you need to add a cronjob too. if you need, then I add the code?

Comment: I dont know anything about cronjob @MohammadAli, if you want to add the code. I would really appreciate your help. Nothing I can say anymore, just big thanks